# iOS UITapGestureRecognizer not working sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Sometimes the selector method "tagClickAtIndex" not getting called.

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tagClickAtIndex:)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];



-(void)tagClickAtIndex:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[_tagArray objectAtIndex:gesture.view.tag]] mutableCopy];
    [mutDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:gesture.view.tag] forKey:@"index"];
    [self.delegate tagClickAtIndex:mutDict];
}
```

Comment: tushars check my answer.It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you forget to set the frame of `label`, the reason it only define the clickable area

```
label.frame  =  CGRectMake(0,0,200,30)
[yourMainview addSubView:label]
```

and set  if you need

```
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

Comment: may be these scenarios it helps you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme

Answer (score 0):

If you are programmatically creating UIlabel,your above code is not working.I tried your code.

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tagClickAtIndex:)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

It does not show anything.As you have not set the frame and add label view,it does not show.

So Then I tried creating UILabel freshly.I set frame,addSubView to self.view and I set the color as well as number of taps for label.

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 200, 100);
label.text = @"click me";
label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Now Tap gesture recognizer for label

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tagClickAtIndex:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

in delegate method I put log,It calls everytime whenever I touch the label

```
-(void)tagClickAtIndex:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
   NSLog(@"The tap is called");
   .........
}
```

The printed statements shows

```
The tap is called
```